# Websocket or Http to develop a mobile app?

Tags: sockets, http, websocket, server

I will deploy a nodejs server for a mobile app, in the mobile app I use websocket to communicate with server.

I want to know if I can stop use the http but just use the websocket?
What are the advantages and disadvantages of this solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to know if I can stop use the http but just use the websocket?

If you have a custom client then yes, this is 100% possible.

But if your client is embedded in a browser then no, 100% is not possible. Because at least you need to perform the websocket handshake over HTTP. Also you need to serve the main page (with embedded JavaScript) over the plain HTTP. Other then that it is completely possible to fully switch to websockets.

> What are the advantages and disadvantages of this solution?

**Advantages**

- Real server push (you can easily notify clients)
- With a proper protocol on top (e.g. json rpc) is extremely efficient compared to HTTP
- Very flexible

**Disadvantages**

- It's pretty much TCP, so you still have to build a custom protocol on top of that. This actually may be hard to implement correctly. Especially if you want to mix textual content (e.g. json) with binary content (e.g. images). It may turn out that you will be reimplementing HTTP over websockets.
- Might be difficult to scale well (again, depending on the top protocol)
- Poorly understood compared to HTTP
- Still quite new, not as many tools as for HTTP

So as you can see most concerns come from facts that it is new and you will have to do lots of manual work with it. That being said my personal opinion is to go for it. If you won't do it then who will? :) At least to have API over websockets and serve static files over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever plan to have your mobile app become a full-fledged website there may be significant reasons to use HTTP+WebSocket as opposed to a WebSocket only. Also, HTTP has been around longer than WebSockets so I'll go ahead and assume that support for HTTP is much more wide-spread than WebSocket support, so if you ever made an API for your app then having HTTP is probably a good thing.